# Stop login popup when doing git pull in VS Code?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Windows Subsystem for Linux with VS Code and the keychain tool to manage my SSH keys. For months I've been able to execute `git pull` from the command line, using my stored SSH keys to access GitHub without logging in. Suddenly, VS Code started showing a pop-up GitHub login window every time I try to do a `git pull`.

I've tried setting `git.enabled` to `false` in my settings and set both "Git: Terminal Authentication" as well as "GitHub: Git Authentication" to false but I still get the same behavior.

Does anyone know how to completely disable this popup window?[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my remotes were https URLs. I did a `git remote set-url upstream git@github.com:<myrepositoryname>` and then everything worked just fine.

Comment: That's still strange. I use http url and don't have this issue. Maybe a keychain problem?